# My manager tells me to have more confidence in my work

Tags: confidence

I was training a new hire at work very last minute today. I have only been with the company for a a little over a year and there are some things I’m still not 100% on knowledge wise. My manager called me in to the office to ask for feedback on the new hire and she told me that I need to have more confidence in my work because she knows that I know what I am doing.

I personally have always struggled with self confidence in pretty much all aspects of my life. I was surprised when I was told I was training the new hire today because it was very out of nowhere.

What advice would you give to me after having my manager tell me to be more confident in my work?

Comment: Your manager is ficinf you advice, follow it.  Have more confidence in yourself.

Comment: Can you say what country you are from?

Comment: @Jack: That comment feels like telling someone who can't swim that they need to swim because their manager told them to swim. Confidence is a learned skill based on past results and interactions. It's not just something people have. It's something they learn.

Comment: What does *ficinf* mean? giving?

Comment: Given your other questions, it seems likely you have been asked to train this person as your direct replacement, meaning they expect you to be terminated soon.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest therapy.

You've told us that you've struggled with self-confidence.

Your manager appears to recognise this and is telling you that you are doing a good job, and you seem to have a hard time believing it.

Talk to a therapist. Often you can talk to one through your work's EAP program.

Answer (score 1):

There's a large difference between being confident and behaving confidently. Being confident really just means believing in yourself that you can do a thing. The fact that you did the thing demonstrates that you *have* confidence. However, for things such as mentorship, coaching, and training, there needs to be a demonstrated display of confidence through your behaviors.

Talk to your manager. Find out what behaviors they're noticing that demonstrate a lack of confidence. Ask for tips on how to correct that. It's not about "faking" it, it's about changing some of the mannerisms and language patterns you're familiar with in order to take your actual confidence and project it outward to other people who really need to see it.

My first tip is based on what I've read in the question. You indicated you're not sure on 100% of the things in your job at this point. That's ok. You don't have to be. What you need is a plan for when you don't know. I'll give you a quick synopsis, and I'll bold the parts of language you need to adopt in order to demonstrate confidence even when you don't know.

> Trainee: "So how do I get the customer's thingy imported over to
> company's whatsit?"
>
> You: "I've only seen a couple parts of that process. **Here's what
> we're going to do.** Let's get Joe Expert on the phone real quick and
> see if he can fill in that gap."

It's not about knowing all the things. It's about projecting a plan of action. Don't know? Here's how you find out. Confidence is about demonstrating action and portraying an attitude of "I'm ready".

Answer (score 1):

*Everyone* has some things that they're not 100% knowledgeable on, not just you. That's normal.

It seems like you may be using the things you don't know yet to discount the things you do know. I suggest trying to focus on the positives more rather than focusing on the few things that you don't know yet.

In terms of overall self-confidence, I strongly recommend reading David Burns, Albert Ellis, and Nathaniel Branden.

Answer (score -1):

What more can we say? It's pretty generic advice.

The fact that your first course of action after hearing your Manager tell you to have more confidence in yourself is to ask strangers on the Internet what to do... proves her assessment correct.

Have more confidence in yourself.

Answer (score -1):

We really can't tell for sure exactly what your manager means unless you give us more **specific examples** of the situations where she tells you to have more confidence in your work.

For example, maybe, she wants you to take more initiatives in daily tasks such as:

1. **Volunteer to lead** and **train new workers** in a project by giving them specific tasks, monitoring their progress, and providing technical help if necessary.
2. Try to solve technical problems in the projects by yourself first for a while if possible. After that, if you still can't solve the problems, then you can come to other senior people or the manager to ask for help.
3. Recommend technical solutions to difficult issues (if you have good solutions) in team meetings even if these are discussions with many seniors in the team.
4. Volunteer to lead new projects if you have worked in that area for a long time, and the manager asks for some senior people to be the lead.
5. Volunteer to represent your team to interface with other departments in your company that work in your same projects such as the test group, project managers, integration group, customer support group, sale teams, etc...

---

The key point is that when the manager tells you to be more confident in yourself, it could be a positive sign as she could see more potentials in you and your skillsets, and she wants you to confidently apply your skills and volunteer to take on more leadership roles in many projects.